# How do you add a domain name to a VPS?

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, domain-name, wiki

I have a VPS with allgamer.net (I use it to play minecraft). I also have a domain name with networksolutions.com

What I want to do is attach that domain name to the VPS. I want to run a wiki on my domain name. If this is possible I can avoid buying another hosting plan just for the wiki.

How do I go about doing this? I have very little knowledge in server administration so any advice you guys have is greatly appreciated!

I'm pretty sure I have to change the DNS in my domain name to the DNS for my VPS, but on allgamer.net's interface there is no discernable place to find out what I need to change it to. Is there a way to find out the DNS via SSH on my VPS?

As well, when I first got my VPS with allgamer.net I filled out a form for it with all my information, but they also wanted a domain name along with it. I gave them the domain name I currently own, but for some reason, it's like it's not connected to the VPS, like if I go to
mydomain.com there's nothing, as well, if I use mydomain.com for my minecraft server, it also doesn't work. It's as if it's serving no purpose by being "attached" to my VPS. Any insights into this?

Thanks for any help you guys can give me.

Comment: Likely you'll want to set both domains to use something like xname.org for dns, then set both dns zones to be your vps ip. Then setup apache name based virtual hosts on apache. The hard part is explaining how to do that in an easy to follow way. Maybe someone else will be able to thrash this out into a step by step guide, but if not hopefully it'll give you  a head start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be a two step process, so stay with me. :)
First as Sam said:
Log in to your DNS manager at network solutions (assuming they are providing your DNS)
Create or edit A records for domain.com, Wiki.domain.com etc to point the IP address of your VPS
 Now we're going to setup our web server; There are millions but I recommend Apache. If you have Ubuntu then run(apt get install httpd) or Centos(yum install httpd). Now we have a web server and you can put files up, but do we want our wiki to be the main site? **If** not then we need to make a Vhost like so 
Main site

```
     <VirtualHost *>
      ServerName otherdomain.com
   ServerAlias www.otherdomain.com  
  DocumentRoot /www/main
</VirtualHost>
```

and for the wlki

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName blog.otherdomain.com
DocumentRoot /www/blogdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

Now using Sftp with most FTP programs you can upload files and go.

I highly suggest you look through Apache documentation to learn what everything does [here](http://apache.org)

Assuming you need PHP and MySQL those are apt get install PHP and mysql (Ubuntu) or Centos(yum install php and mysql)
I use a program called [navicat](http://www.navicat.com/en/) to admin MYSQL. There is a free version you can get there.

If you feel you need a control panel still; a good free one can be found at [webmin](http://webmin.com)

Answer (score 1):

The process  would be something along these lines:

- Log in to your DNS manager at network solutions (assuming they are providing your DNS)
- Create or edit A records for domain.com, www.domain.com etc to point the IP address of your VPS
- Setup a web server on your VPS to handle this traffic
- Profit!

Answer (score -1):

check this : Full guide to help you setting up your VPS
[How To Setup Ubuntu VPS And Link It To A Domain Name](http://www.thwebexpert.com/2014/08/how-to-install-ubuntu-vps-and-link-it.html)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on ServerFault, because if the target of the link goes away, your answer becomes useless.  Instead, please describe the method here.  You can also provide the link.

Comment: ok,  I understood ; I will describe the method next time