# How to configure a VPS to resolve a domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver

This one will be a dummy and a newbie question. I searched on the internet and maybe i looked around for the wrong things. Here is my case:
My friend gave me a domain name(abc.com) and a nameserver(ns3.xyz.com) and a VPS. The he wanted me to work out with these. I need to connect the dots and configure the VPS to resolve the domain name.

I've installed apache and with the ip address of the server, i can see the test page but i couldn't achieve to see it via domain name.

I go through some of the tutorials about bind. (e.g: http://www.xenocafe.com/tutorials/dns_linux/redhat/dns_linux_redhat-part3.php) However none of them worked out.

I would be very grateful, if you can give me some hints or a reference for a kickstart.

As i mentioned first, this is probably a very dummy question from a newbie, sorry for that. Thanks

p.s-1: The system is a CentOS
p.s-2: I also check out [How do you add a domain name to a VPS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/235572/how-do-you-add-a-domain-name-to-a-vps) however i don't have any access to a DNS manager. Is there a way to prove or disprove that DNS manager configuration is OK?

Comment: Re: ps-2, you can run `dig mydomain.com +short` on your server. If you don't get any response, then your DNS is not set up.

Comment: Yeap I don't get any response. Then what should i do? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however i don't have any access to a DNS manager

Ask the DNS provider to point the domain `abc.com` to your server's IP address.

> Is there a way to prove or disprove that DNS manager configuration is
>   OK?

If it is OK, use some DNS lookup utilities to check to make sure that your domain can resolve to the right IP address, for e.g:

```
$ nslookup serverfault.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   serverfault.com
Address: 64.34.119.12
```

Comment: To get the right response from nslookup, don't i need to make any configuration on server(specifically on bind)? My friend is in touch with the DNS provider and he says that he points the nameserver ns2.xyz.com to our server's ip address therefore he claims that i should configure bind to resolve that nameserver and domain name. Is this statement wrong?

Comment: Now I have access to DNS provider. I entered A Host(@) Points to "My.ip" is that correct? Do i need to modifiy other fields or do i have to wait 2 to 48 hours for my modification to become active?

Comment: Okey i resolved my problem. I used ns of the DNS provider and point my domain to server's ip address. Thanks a lot